# Derivative at a point

Tags: integration, limits, derivatives, continuity

I have a to solve the following question.

Q: Find $(f'(0))^2$ when

$$f\left(x\right)=\cases{\frac{\sin^2\left(3x\right)}{2x}, x\neq0\\0, x=0}$$

Can anyone please guide me as to how to go about such questions. I have tried taking the derivative of the function and then solved it when $x=0$, but I didn't get the correct answer.

Thank you!

Comment: How did you take the derivative here? Hint: you should use the limit definition of the derivative (not just the quotient rule) to calculate the derivative of this piecewise-defined function at $x=0$.

Comment: If you find any of the below answers useful, consider accepting it by clicking the tickmark button on its left.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use $$f'(0)=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}$$
What you get is $$f'(0)=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin^2(3x)}{2x^2}=\lim_{x\to 0}\left(\frac{\sin(3x)}{3x}\right)^2\frac92$$
Can you take it from here?

Comment: Yes. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

You'll find the answer instantly using some elementary asymptotic analysis:

As $\sin u\sim_0 u$, we have
$$f'(0)=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{f(x)-f(0)}x=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin^2 3x}{2x^2}$$
and
$$\frac{\sin^2 3x}{2x^2}\sim_0 \frac{(3x)^2}{2x^2}.$$